# SWIFT How to create a NSCoding Subclass and call it from another class?

Tags: ios, inheritance, swift, nscoding

I found this black of code on NSCoding and it almost does want I want it to.  the link for where I found it is below.
How do I create a NSCoding class and user in in other classes?  The below code dies not work.  I hope some can help me with this.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class User: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as String
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
    }
}


//new class where I want to set and get the object

class MyNewClass: UIViewController {

    let user = User(name: "Mike")
    let encodedUser = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(user)
    let decodedUser = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(encodedUser) as User

}

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589933/nskeyedunarchiver-fails-to-decode-a-custom-object-in-swift
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm cutting and pasting from my own project below.  I have limited this to one string parameter to store to file.  But you can more of different types.  You can paste this into a single swift file and use it as the ViewController plus added classes to test.  It demonstrates using NSCoding with swift syntax to save and retrieve data in an object.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var instanceData = Data()
        instanceData.name = "testName"
        ArchiveData().saveData(nameData: instanceData)
        let retrievedData = ArchiveData().retrieveData() as Data
        println(retrievedData.name)

    }
}

class Data: NSObject {

    var name: String = ""

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as String
    }

    override init() {
    }
}

class ArchiveData:NSObject {

    var documentDirectories:NSArray = []
    var documentDirectory:String = ""
    var path:String = ""

    func saveData(#nameData: Data) {
        documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as String
        path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.archive")

        if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(nameData, toFile: path) {
            //println("Success writing to file!")
        } else {
            println("Unable to write to file!")
        }
    }

    func retrieveData() -> NSObject {
        var dataToRetrieve = Data()
        documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as String
        path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("data.archive")
        if let dataToRetrieve2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as? Data {
            dataToRetrieve = dataToRetrieve2 as Data
        }
        return(dataToRetrieve)
    }
}
```